# Repeat Until Loop with if, elseif, and else in Lua

Tags: lua, string-comparison

I'm new to Lua and I have been having a problem with this bit of code. It is supposed to verify user input with `io.read` then run the correct `if`, `elseif`, or `else` statement. Once the user  puts in the correct response the code should end. For some reason the code will only run the initial `if` statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
repeat
    resp1 = io.read()

    if resp1 == "Yes" or "yes" then
        print("Well alright then, come on in.")
        print("Let me just take your blood sample like all the rest and you'll be good to go.")
    elseif resp1 == "No" or "no" then
        print("Oh, your not? Then why are you up here?")
        print("Oh nevermind then. None of my business anyways. All I'm supposed to do is take a blood sample for everyone who enters the town.")
        print("So let us get that over with now, shall we?")
    else
        print("Please respond with Yes or No")
    end
until resp1 == "Yes" or resp1 == "No" or resp1 == "no" or resp1 == "yes"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is with this line:

```
if resp1 == "Yes" or "yes" then
```

These are two separate expressions, and in Lua, everything except `nil` and `false` are truthy values, so it will pick that `if` statement to run, because a string in Lua, even an empty one, evaluates to `true` as far as conditions are concerned. If it helps you understand, think of it like this:

```
if (resp1 == "Yes") or ("yes") then
```

If you actually wanted to compare `resp1` against two values, you would do it like this:

```
if resp1 == "Yes" or resp1 == "yes" then
```

However, this is a simpler solution for what you're trying to achieve:

```
if resp1:lower() == 'yes' then
```

---

In fact, you could clean up your loop, too. Make it more readable. Make use of multi-line strings instead of multiple `print` calls and `break` as well.

```
repeat
    resp1 = io.read():lower() -- read in lowercased input

    if resp1 == 'yes' then
        print[[Well alright then, come on in.
Let me just take your blood sample like all the rest and you'll be good to go.]]
        break -- exit from the loop here
    elseif resp1 == 'no' then
        print[[Oh, your not? Then why are you up here?
Oh nevermind then. None of my business anyways. All I'm supposed to do is take a blood sample for everyone who enters the town.
So let us get that over with now, shall we?]]
        break
    else
        print'Please respond with Yes or No'
    end

until false -- repeat forever until broken
```

Answer (score 0):

I did that way...

```
repeat
 print("Please respond with Yes or No.")
    resp1 = io.read()

    if resp1 == "Yes" or resp1 == "yes" then
        print("Well alright then, come on in.")
        print("Let me just take your blood sample like all the rest and you'll be good to go.")

    elseif resp1 == "No" or resp1 == "no" then
        print("Oh, your not? Then why are you up here?")
        print("Oh nevermind then. None of my business anyways. All I'm supposed to do is take a blood sample for everyone who enters the town.")
        print("So let us get that over with now, shall we?")
        else
        print("Please, use just yes or no!!")
     end

   until resp1 == "Yes" or resp1 == "No" and resp1 == "no" or resp1 == "yes"
```